# Cannot type into input field in React

Tags: reactjs

I am struggling with my input field & haven't been able to find a working solution. I somehow cannot type anything into them. Any suggestions on how I could solve it?

Is there anything wrong with my onChange() that I am overseeing? I don't get any errors though. That's why it is so weird.

```
export default class SignIn extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      email: '',
      id: '',
    };
  }

handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  signup = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({
      id: uuid()
    }, () => {
      axios.post('https://api.xyz.co/api/signup?id=' + this.state.id + '&email=' + this.state.email + '&name=' + this.state.name)
      .then((result) => {
        console.log("submitted mail to join community");
        console.log('hi' + this.state.name)
        this.jump();
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });
  }

jump() {
        this.props.history.push({
          pathname: `/sceneries/8`,
          state: {
            name: this.state.name
          },
        })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div id="signIn">
        <form action="" method="post" className="form" >
            <input type="text" placeholder="Your first name" value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <input
              type="email"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              placeholder="Your email"
            />
            <button id="submitEmail" type="submit" onClick={this.signup}>
              Join us
            </button>
          </form>
</div>
  );
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Try adding name attribute to input 'email'.

Comment: You're missing "name" attributes from your inputs. In your `handleChange` function you're destructuring `const { name, value } = e.target`, but you don't set the `name` attribute on your inputs.

Comment: You need to add a `name` attribute to each of your `<input>` elements.  ie:  `<input name="email" type="email" value=.....>`

Comment: Although on SO we don't mind helping, you would have found the error easily if you'd have put a `console.log` in your `handleChange` function and logged `name` and `value`. The best thing to do when something doesn't work is follow the flow of data and log things along the way to make sure the data is what you expect it to be. If everything looks as expected and it still doesn't work, then that's the time to post a question on SO.

Comment: [e.target.name]: e.target.value in handlechange in the set state after adding the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are simply missing the `name` attributes on your `<input>` elements:

Your `render` method should look like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div id="signIn">
        <form action="" method="post" className="form" >
          <input
            name="name"  //name attribute here
            type="text"
            placeholder="Your first name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          <input
            name="email" //name attribute here
            type="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            placeholder="Your email"
          />
          <button id="submitEmail" type="submit" onClick={this.signup}>
            Join us
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `name` property to your `input`.

`e.target.name` is not available in your code.